# How do I docker pull the highest semantic version instead of latest version?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Hello this may sound like an odd request, but I don't own the docker repository and have to workaround this problem. How do I `docker pull` the highest semantic version like 12.4.6 and higher?

Here are the reasons I wanted to do this.

1. I don't own the repository; thus, versioning is not in my control.
2. The repository has no latest version. I am guessing because latest version is implicit.
3. The repository often removes the older version when newer one is added, thus, I have to find the latest version frequently.
4. I don't want test version. The most recently published version can be alpha.3.1.2 and I only want version that is in the semantic version format `xxx.xxx.xxx`
5. I am not worried about an inconsistent environment because I want to use the latest production version.

I am using a dockerfile, thus dockerfile solution is preferred. But both command line and dockerfile solutions are great. Is there a way to pull the docker image using a wildcard similar to package.json in NodeJS?

Thank you

Comment: It would be pretty easy to write a tool that extract a list of tags for a given image, sorts them using a version compare, and returns the highest version. [`skopeo list-tags`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) will get you the list of tags without needed to write any code, and after that it's just filtering and sorting.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://github.com/ryandaniels/docker-script-find-latest-image-tag

Comment: @larsks and Sebastian Liebscher sounds like there is nothing built in. I will use those suggested solutions. Thank you.